# Splitting a comma- and semicolon-delimited string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, string-matching

I'm trying to split a string containing two entries and each entry has a specific format:

- Category (e.g. `active site`/`region`) which is followed by a `:`
- Term (e.g. `His, Glu`/`nucleotide-binding motif A`) which is followed by a `,`

Here's the string that I want to split:

```
string <- "active site: His, Glu,region: nucleotide-binding motif A,"
```

This is what I have tried so far. Except for the two empty substrings, it produces the desired output.

```
unlist(str_extract_all(string, ".*?(?=,(?:\\w+|$))"))

[1] "active site: His, Glu"              ""                                   "region: nucleotide-binding motif A"
[4] ""
```

How do I get rid of the empty substrings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the empty strings because `.*?` can also match an empty string where this assertion `(?=,(?:\\w+|$))` is true

You can exclude matching a colon or comma using a negated character class before matching `:`

```
[^:,\n]+:.*?(?=,(?:\w|$))
```

**Explanation**

- `[^:,\n]+` Match 1+ chars other than `:` `,` or a newline
- `:` Match the colon
- `.*?` Match any char as least as possbiel
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that what is directly to the right from the current position:

  - `,` Match literally
  - `(?:\w|$)` Match either a single word char, or assert the end of the string
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3lycNW/1) | [R demo](https://tio.run/##LY1LDsIgFEXnrOKFOAClLoBoiCPdg2hDW2xegjR5gJ/EvWMbnd0zOOdSrQE7cvQWKRPGkSRjvwW7BrjrMz48JMxewwmTgmMoivyIU9QQSx/8lHHwTYdxWKT7jDc4KM5KDJjykm39K9Ncal0I/xsF/HzVytp42ejt2gizV8Joa5@flZRcSlbrFw)

```
string <- "active site: His, Glu,region: nucleotide-binding motif A,"
unlist(str_extract_all(string, "[^:,\\n]+:.*?(?=,(?:\\w|$))"))
```

Output

```
[1] "active site: His, Glu"              "region: nucleotide-binding motif A"
```

Answer (score 2):

Much longer and not as elegant as @The fourth bird +1,
but it works:

```
library(stringr)

string2 <- strsplit(string, "([^,]+,[^,]+),", perl = TRUE)[[1]][2]
string1 <- str_replace(string, string2, "")
string <- str_replace_all(c(string1, string2), '\\,$', '')
```

```
> string
[1] "active site: His, Glu"             
[2] "region: nucleotide-binding motif A"
```